# How to set LD_LIBRARY_PATH permanently?

Tags: command-line, environment-variables, paths

I am using Ubuntu 16. I want to use `cfmid` for my project. When I set `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` in terminal, I can get output of the `cfmid` library:

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/home/lclab/installed/boost/boost_1_65_0:/home/lclab/installed/rdkit/rdkit-Release_2016_03_1/lib:/home/lclab/installed/lp/lp_solve_5.5.2.5_dev_ux64
```

But, when I close the terminal session and open a new one, I want to add `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` again.

How can I set this permanently?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You just need to add the following line to your `~/.bashrc` file:

```
LD_LIBRARY_PATH="$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/home/lclab/installed/boost/boost_1_65_0:/home/lclab/installed/rdkit/rdkit-Release_2016_03_1/lib:/home/lclab/installed/lp/lp_solve_5.5.2.5_dev_ux64"
```

The file is loaded every time you open a terminal. If you want to set the variable once when you login, add the line to `~/.profile` instead.

Due to [a bug in the `openssh` and/or `xorg` package](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/openssh/+bug/47958) the variable may be unset again on your system so that using the dotfiles as recommended above doesn’t work. There are several possible solutions:

- disable the initialisation of `ssh-agent` in `/etc/X11/Xsession.options`:

  ```
  sudo sed -i 's/use-ssh-agent/no-use-ssh-agent/' /etc/X11/Xsession.options
  ```

  This won’t do any harm, see the explanation in [this bug report comment](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/xorg/+bug/366728/comments/21).
- the workaround from [a duplicate bug report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/xorg/+bug/380360):

  ```
  echo STARTUP=\"/usr/bin/env LD_LIBRARY_PATH=\${LD_LIBRARY_PATH} \${STARTUP}\" | sudo tee /etc/X11/Xsession.d/90preserve_ld_library_path
  ```
- use a `/etc/ld.so.conf.d/*.conf` file as explained in [this bug report comment](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/xorg/+bug/366728/comments/15) (see also [How to set the environmental variable LD_LIBRARY_PATH in linux](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13428910)):

  ```
  echo "/opt/qt-mobility-src-1.0.0-tp2/install/lib" | sudo tee /etc/ld.so.conf.d/qt-mobility.conf && sudo ldconfig -v
  ```

Comment: In Ubuntu 18.04: I was setting `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` in `~/.pam_environment` and was always unset after reboot. The first solution solved it. (replace `use-ssh-agent` by `no-use-ssh-agent` in `/etc/X11/Xsession.options`)